# converse of open mapping theorem in functional analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X,Y$ be two Banach spaces over $\mathbb K$ and let $T:X\to Y$ be $\mathbb K-$linear and continuous . Then how to show that 'if T is open then it is surjective?'

Please someone help..

Thank you..

Comment: Consider the image of the open unit ball and show that it contains a ball. Conclude by using homogeneity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse is true.

We have from hypothesis of the converse statement that $T(x)$ is an  open subspace of $Y$ $(1)$

Thus $T(X)$ ha a nonempty interior(actualy it is equal to its interior).

Thus exists a point $z \in T(X)$ and $r>0$ such that $B(z,r) \subseteq T(X)$,and because $T(X)$ is a subspace and $z \in T(X)$ we have that $$B(0,r)=z-B(z,r)\subseteq T(X)$$

Now we will prove that $Y \subseteq T(X)$

Let $y \in Y$,then $\frac{r}{2}\frac{y}{||y||} \in B(0,r)$ because $$||\frac{r}{2}\frac{y}{||y||}||=\frac{r}{2}<r \Rightarrow \frac{r}{2}\frac{y}{||y||} \in B(0,r) \subseteq T(X) \Rightarrow y=\frac{2||y||}{r}\frac{r}{2}\frac{y}{||y||} \in B(0,r) \subseteq T(X)$$ because $T(X)$ is a subspace.

Thus $y \in T(X)\Rightarrow Y \subseteq T(X)$ $(2)$

Combining $(1),(2)$ we have that $T(X)=Y$ thus $T$ is onto.

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ is an open mapping, then

1) the image of the unit ball, $T(B(0,1))$ is open,

2) the image of the unit ball contains an open ball centered at 0 with radius $r>0$, and

3) if a point $y\in Y$ has norm $\alpha$, then $y \in T( B(0,1+ \alpha/r))$.

This "proof" works for if $K$ is the real number field.  I'm not sure if it works for finite fields.

Comment: When one speaks of 'Banach space', it is always a real or complex vector space. Exotic generalizations surely exist but that's not the case of this question for sure.

Comment: I will give another answer for the question. It follows from the following result: Let $X$ a normed vector space and $V$ is a subspace of $X$. If $V$ contains a nonempty open set $U$, then $V = X$. As T(X) is a subspace of $Y$ and $T(B(0,1))$ is an open set in $T(X)$, we have $T(X) = Y$. Actually we don't need X,Y to be Banach spaces, not even continuity.